# Pricing a zero coupon callable bond

Tags: simulations, european-options, zero-coupon, callable-bonds, black

Suppose I have a 20-year zero bond with a call date in 10 years and a zero interest rate of 2%, which is currently valued at a Z-spread of 100. Now I would like to evaluate the right of termination and proceed as follows:
I calculate the forward interest rate in 10 years, add the Z spread and get the appropriate interest rate at which the debtor could borrow money again at the time of termination. I assume that the interest rate in the future will be logarithmically normally distributed and simulate the 10 annual interest rate with an assumed volatility. I calculate the value of the option from the realizations of the simulation and the agreed repayment rate. After drawing 1000 random numbers, I determine the average and discount it with today's 10-year interest rate plus the Z spread. I take this value as the option value.
Is this procedure correct? Unfortunately, I can never get the prices from Bloomberg.

Comment: How realistic is it for the Z-spread (credit spread) to not change in 10 years?

Comment: Not realistic but what is a better and pragmatic approach?